# Selenium - 'element not visible' with lower specificity

Tags: javascript, selenium

Just getting started with selenium and selenium-webdriver.
I am trying to open up google and click on the `anchor` tag.
Please find the below code.

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
   withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
   build();

driver.get('https://www.google.com/');
driver.wait(function () {
  return driver.isElementPresent(webdriver.By.css('a'));
}, 2000);
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css('a')).click();  

driver.quit();
```

selenium throws `ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible` error for the selector `'a'`.

However, if I increase the specificity `'#fsl>a'` selenium is able to click the item.

Any pointer would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > Raised to indicate that although an element is present on the DOM, it is not visible, and so is not able to be interacted with.

[ElementNotVisibleError](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Error/ElementNotVisibleError.html), helped me to debug the problem.

**It has nothing to do with specificity**, but **visibility**.

When I perform `document.querySelector('a')`, it returns the very first `a` and that is not visible in the `document`.

[image]